# How to add url file to zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, zip

I have a zip file with the following structure:

```
my_zip.zip
|-file1.txt
|-folder1/
    |-file2.txt
```

I want to add `some_file` **from url** to the `folder1`. I know that I can do something like:

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> z = zipfile.ZipFile("my_zip.zip", "w")
>>> z.write("some_file")
```

But, there are two issues:

- How to add the `some_file` to that specific `folder1`?
- Should I download the `some_file` to my PC and next use `z.write('path/to_my/local/some_file')`? There is no way to do it directly from url to the zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ZipFile.writestr(arcname, data)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr).

To write to a folder in the zipfile, you just write the foldername as if you were writing to a folder in a folder (So `folder1/some_file`).

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile("my_zip.zip", "w")
page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com/')  # Change to website
z.writestr('folder1/some_file', page.read())
```

Comment: Something is wrong. When I try to open the zip file, Archive Manager returns `An error occurred while loading the archive`.

Comment: Ok. It was easy to fix. First, change the mode to `"a"`, otherwise the zip file will be build from scratch, loosing previous files stored in it. Second, add `z.close()` at the end of the script.